# How to replace or comment double quotes in a CSV file when the doublequotes are preceded by a number

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Ubuntu 16.04
GNU bash, version 4.3.48

I have some csv files that are not being parsed correctly because of `""` that are placed inside the fields to represent inches.

In our csv file, columns with multiple values must be separated by commas and then the column must be wrapped with double quotes like so:
`"one","two","three, three, three, three","four","five"`

Example of the foreign `""`

```
... star","Radio data system,Radio: AM/FM 8"" Diagonal Color Touch Screen,Single Slot CD/MP3 Player, Nicer","Siera ...
... star","Rear Wheelhouse Liners,Thin Profile LED Fog Lamps,4.2"" Diagonal Color Display Driver Info Center,Chevrolet Connected Access","Chevrolet ...
```

I know I can use sed to replace the "" quotes like so 
`sed -i 's/""/inch/g' filename.csv`

But this causes issues when a column does not contain information, like so:

```
... star","Program. Exp. 10/01/2018","","All Star Edition,LT Plus Package, somemore ...","Felix ...
```

So I am looking for a way to replace double quotes when they are preceded by a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
line1='... star","Radio data system,Radio: AM/FM 8"" Diagonal Color Touch Screen,Single Slot CD/MP3 Player, Nicer","Siera ...'
line2='... star","Rear Wheelhouse Liners,Thin Profile LED Fog Lamps,4.2"" Diagonal Color Display Driver Info Center,Chevrolet Connected Access","Chevrolet ...'
line3='... star","Program. Exp. 10/01/2018","","All Star Edition,LT Plus Package, somemore ...","Felix ...'

echo $line1 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)""/\1inch/g'
echo $line2 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)""/\1inch/g'
echo $line3 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)""/\1inch/g'
```

- `\([0-9]\)`: any number from 0 to 9.  The parenthesis are there since we need that keep number in the replacement.
- `\1inch`: \1 is replaced by the number we kept in the matching part, "inch", well that is obvious ;-)
- Not sure if you want to keep one ", that would be done with one simple modification:  `echo $line3 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)""/\1inch"/g'`

Comment: ```,"",``` The missing values are not always missing so we don't need to mess with anything that is preceded by a comma and ends with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to (and should not!) replace or remove those embedded quotes. The second quote is there to escape the double quote inside your field.

Taking your first example:

```
"one","two","three, three, three, three","four","five"
```

Say we want to insert `"test"` inside the third field, including those quotes:

```
"one","two","three, "test", three, three, three","four","five"
```

This would be a problem for the parser. Therefore those quotes have to be escaped with another quote:

```
"one","two","three, ""test"", three, three, three","four","five"
```

See [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) for more details on the format.

So in your csv file the data is correct (the quotes are properly escaped):

```
,"Radio data system,Radio: AM/FM 8"" Diagonal",
```

All you have to do is tell the parser that the fields are quoted and (optionally) embedded quotes are escaped with another quote (some systems use `\` to escape those quotes).

Removing or replacing those pairs of quotes before parsing could introduce all kinds of problems and errors.

Comment: the double quotes in my instance stands for inches and I wanted to remove them as the word inches looks a lot better in this application than "". I do understand what you are saying and I appreciate it very much.